# printing numbers as a triangle in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

In this problem the user has to input the starting number and the size of the triangle.if starting number is 5 and size of the triangle is 6 the output must be like this.

```
5
19 6
18 20 7
17 25 21 8 
16 24 23 22 9
15 14 13 12 11 10
```

I have already tried this problem and their is a error with my code. Can someone help me to find the error with this.

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        //first number
        int n=in.nextInt();
        //size of the triangle
        int k=in.nextInt();
        int [][]arr=new int[k][k];
        int sizec=k,sizer=k,rstart=0,cstart=0,rend=k-2,cend=k-2,p=0;
        while(sizer>1&&sizec>1){
            int g=cstart;
            for(int i=rstart;i<sizer;i++){
                arr[g][i]=n;
                n++;
                g++;

            }
            for(int i=rend;i>=rstart;i--){
                arr[cend+1][i]=n;
                n++;

            }
            for(int i=cend;i>cstart;i--){
                arr[i][rstart]=n;
                n++;

            }
            rstart++;
            cstart+=2;
            rend-=2;
            sizec-=2;
            sizer-=2;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<k;j++){
            for(int h=0;h<j+1;h++){
                System.out.print(arr[j][h]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to me your algo way to complex just for that you need to rethink the way you want to output that to many for loop i would have done it with one while loop and one for loop inside the while loop, the size triangle will be condition to stop the loop if you need a example code i can provide.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a

```
cend--;
```

Put it there:

```
    sizer-=2;
    cend--;
}
```

I would also recommend that you change your variable names into words so that it is possible for other people to read your code.  For example, cend could be "columnEnd".